# How to implement that - generic method ro create result

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have a bunch of method like these:

```
public Result createSomething1(A a, B b, C c) {} 
public Result createSomethung2(B a, C c, D d) {}
```

Always I need to create Result object with updated (or not) object above using fluent api and status like that:

```
Result result = new Result.withA(a)
  .withB(b)
  .withC(c)
  ...withStatus("success");
```

I don't want to create separated method for each of set parameters.

How I can write generic method which be able to create Result object from undefined numbers of parameters?

For example:

pseudo-code

```
Result createResult(A a, B b, C c ...) { 
  return with(a, b, c, ...) 
}
```

using

```
Result createSomething1(A a, B b) {
  // business processing ending error 
  Result result = createResult(a, b);
  result.withStatus("error")
  return result;
}

Result createSomething2(A a, C c, M m) {
  // business processing ending  
  Result result = createResult(c, m);
  a.setFoo("foo");
  result.withA(a);
  return result;
}
```

?

Comment: So you already create your result objects like in the second code piece and want to warp an API around it? Why don't you make that itself your API? Any other constraints that make it impossible?

Comment: Maybe use Java8 Streams and Lambdas? Unfortunately I don't fully understand your question though

Comment: What is Result in fact ? Is that an object with a status attribute, and 3 other attributes of whatever type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could investigate using Streams  in Java 8

This is similar to a Linux pipe

```
Stream s1 = Stream.builder().add(1).add(4).add(7).build();
```

or something like the following which passes each value of your array into your method

```
 int [] myArray = {3,2,5,7,33,90};
 int result = Arrays.stream(myArray).somemethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your parameters classes have common base case class like that:
    public class Parameter {
      ...
    }

```
public class A extends Parameter {
  ...
}

public class B extends Parameter {
  ...
}
```

than you can use varargs

```
public Result with(Parameter... p) {
  some code to process parameters
  return result //with parameters setted
}
```

p - array of Parameters. Now you can call

```
result.with(a, b, c)
```

or

```
result.with(a).with(b,c)
```

Comment: all java classes are subclasses of Object. So you can use it instead of Parameter class. But it need additional type checking

Comment: `Parameter` may be useful as tagging interface.

Comment: Good idea of converting Parameter to interface

Answer (score 1):

Storing parameters in a map would make this very easy:

```
Map<String, Object> params;

public Result with(Object... newParams) {
    for (Object param : newParams) {
        params.put(param.getClass().getName(), param);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Usage example:

```
 new Result().with(a).with(b).with(c);
```

or, equivalently:

```
 new Result().with(a,b,c);
```

---

Edit:

If you necessarily have to use class fields rather than storing them in a map, you can access them using reflection:

```
public Result with(Object... newParams) {
    for (Object param : newParams) {
        setField(param);
    }
    return this;
}

public void setField(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = Result.class.getFields();

    for (Field field: fields) {
        if (field.getType().equals(o.getClass())) {
            field.set(this, o);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the **Builder** design pattern, as implemented by **StringBuilder**.

Create a `ResultBuilder` class with one or more methods `with(...)` that returns itself. That way, you can chain calls to pass all your parameters.
Finally, create a methode `toResult()` to create your Result object using the given parameters.

It will look like this:

```
public class ResultBuilder {
    public ResultBuilder with(A a) {
        // ...
        return this;
    }

    public ResultBuilder with(B b) {
        // ...
        return this;
    }

    public ResultBuilder with(C c) {
        // ...
        return this;
    }

    public Result toResult() {
        final Result result = new Result();
        result.setA(/* ... */);
        result.setB(/* ... */);
        result.setC(/* ... */);
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Result result = new ResultBuilder().with(a).with(b).with(c).toResult();
```